# How to call this relationship for first order conditions?

Tags: optimization, terminology

I have a function $f(x,y)$ and the partial derivatives are of the form
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=g(x,y)h(x,y)
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=k(x,y)h(x,y)
$$
Suppose $g(x,y)$ and $k(x,y)$ are always positive, then the two partial derivatives' sign will be exactly the sign of $h(x,y)$. In other words, they will be positive, negative or zero simultaneously.

However, I don't know is there any terms which describe such situation. I was thinking about using "proportional to" or the sign $\varpropto$. But seems that it is not accurate, no?

Comment: What's the range/codomain of this function?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. There is no restriction on the range or codomain. Does it matter a lot?

Comment: whenever one's interested in anything related to first-order derivatives, a natural reaction is "read anything around Jacobian matrices and determinants in your favourite book(s)!", and the determinant may be specially interesting in this case, as you're interested in signs of stuff, but of course the determinant only exists for square matrices, so it's relevant to know if this $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ or not